# Ver web desde VM en Google Cloud Plataform

Tags: web, servidor, google-cloud-platform, windows-server

No tengo mucha experiencia en manejo de servidores, pero tengo toda una app web montada en una VM (Windows Server 2016) de Google Cloud Plataform y me gustaría que se puedan conectar a mi web desde fuera, pero no se como.

En local se que se puede poniendo mi ip/web.html pero con el Server no se conecta, me da error.

¿Que tengo que configurar?

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud por defecto tiene todos los puertos cerrados, por lo tanto si desea que tu web sea visible desde afuera, debes crear una regla de Firewall que permita acceso al puerto en el que esta expuesta tu web.

Por lo general para web se utilizan los puertos 80 (creo que este es tu caso) y el 443 que es para https.

## Añade un Tag a tu VM

Lo primero que debes hacer es asignar un Tag de red a tu VM. Para eso le pones editar y agregas un tag representativo de la accion que deseas realizar, por ejemplo.

[image: tags de red]

Recuerda grabar antes de salir.

## Crea una regla de Firewall

Para poder crear una regla de firewal debes ir a la consola web. A Redes VPC > Reglas de Firewall

[image: crear regla de firewall]

Dale un nombre a la regla y asociala con tu VM mediante el tag que creaste, tal como se ve en la imágen.

[image: Crear regla]

En este caso el 0.0.0.0/0 es para que puedan entrar a tu web desde cualquier IP en el mundo.

Y finalmente estable el puerto tcp que quieres abrir, es este caso el 80.

Recuerda grabar, dale algunos minutos y vuele a probar si tienes acceso a tu web desde afuera.